# No errors in log, but app-error in browser

Tags: heroku

I'm learning Heroku. I tried to deploy a Node.js app on Heroku. Build seems to be successful, but the browser shows App-error.

https://warm-coast-28316.herokuapp.com/

Why?

Here is the log. Is there something suspicios?

```
-----> Node.js app detected    
-----> Creating runtime environmen
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error    
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true    
       NODE_ENV=production    
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true    
-----> Installing binaries    
       engines.node (package.json):  >=0.12.7 <0.13    
       engines.npm (package.json):   ~2.11.3



       Resolving node version >=0.12.7 <0.13 via semver.io...

       Downloading and installing node 0.12.18...

       Resolving npm version ~2.11.3 via semver.io...

       Downloading and installing npm 2.11.3 (replacing version 2.15.11)...

-----> Restoring cache

       Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)

-----> Building dependencies

       Installing node modules (package.json)



       > ws@0.4.32 install /tmp/build_beb218743747080f27aa5afd85781f8f/vheinitz-reatha-7a0950a/node_modules/node-hl7/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws

       > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)



       make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_beb218743747080f27aa5afd85781f8f/vheinitz-reatha-7a0950a/node_modules/node-hl7/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'

       CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o

       SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node

       COPY Release/bufferutil.node

       CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o

       SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node

       COPY Release/validation.node

       make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_beb218743747080f27aa5afd85781f8f/vheinitz-reatha-7a0950a/node_modules/node-hl7/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'

       module@0.0.1 node_modules/module



       periodic-task@0.1.2 node_modules/periodic-task



       cookie-parser@1.3.5 node_modules/cookie-parser

       ├── cookie@0.1.3

       └── cookie-signature@1.0.6



       debug@2.2.0 node_modules/debug

       └── ms@0.7.1



       jsonfile@2.4.0 node_modules/jsonfile

       └── graceful-fs@4.1.11



       morgan@1.5.3 node_modules/morgan

       ├── basic-auth@1.0.4

       ├── depd@1.0.1

       └── on-finished@2.2.1 (ee-first@1.1.0)



       string@3.3.3 node_modules/string



       node-mv@0.1.3 node_modules/node-mv

       ├── progress@1.1.8

       ├── async@0.9.2

       └── commander@2.9.0 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)



       serve-favicon@2.2.1 node_modules/serve-favicon

       ├── fresh@0.2.4

       ├── parseurl@1.3.1

       ├── ms@0.7.1

       └── etag@1.6.0 (crc@3.2.1)



       gm@1.23.0 node_modules/gm

       ├── array-series@0.1.5

       ├── array-parallel@0.1.3

       └── cross-spawn@4.0.2 (lru-cache@4.0.2, which@1.2.12)



       express@4.12.4 node_modules/express

       ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6

       ├── fresh@0.2.4

       ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.0

       ├── parseurl@1.3.1

       ├── content-type@1.0.2

       ├── utils-merge@1.0.0

       ├── cookie@0.1.2

       ├── methods@1.1.2

       ├── escape-html@1.0.1

       ├── range-parser@1.0.3

       ├── vary@1.0.1

       ├── finalhandler@0.3.6

       ├── serve-static@1.9.3

       ├── content-disposition@0.5.0

       ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3

       ├── depd@1.0.1

       ├── on-finished@2.2.1 (ee-first@1.1.0)

       ├── qs@2.4.2

       ├── etag@1.6.0 (crc@3.2.1)

       ├── send@0.12.3 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.7.1, mime@1.3.4)

       ├── proxy-addr@1.0.10 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@1.0.5)

       ├── type-is@1.6.14 (media-typer@0.3.0, mime-types@2.1.14)

       └── accepts@1.2.13 (negotiator@0.5.3, mime-types@2.1.14)



       body-parser@1.16.0 node_modules/body-parser

       ├── bytes@2.4.0

       ├── content-type@1.0.2

       ├── depd@1.1.0

       ├── on-finished@2.3.0 (ee-first@1.1.1)

       ├── raw-body@2.2.0 (unpipe@1.0.0)

       ├── http-errors@1.5.1 (setprototypeof@1.0.2, inherits@2.0.3, statuses@1.3.1)

       ├── qs@6.2.1

       ├── debug@2.6.0 (ms@0.7.2)

       ├── type-is@1.6.14 (media-typer@0.3.0, mime-types@2.1.14)

       └── iconv-lite@0.4.15



       request@2.79.0 node_modules/request

       ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0

       ├── aws-sign2@0.6.0

       ├── oauth-sign@0.8.2

       ├── forever-agent@0.6.1

       ├── tunnel-agent@0.4.3

       ├── caseless@0.11.0

       ├── stringstream@0.0.5

       ├── isstream@0.1.2

       ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1

       ├── extend@3.0.0

       ├── aws4@1.5.0

       ├── uuid@3.0.1

       ├── combined-stream@1.0.5 (delayed-stream@1.0.0)

       ├── qs@6.3.0

       ├── form-data@2.1.2 (asynckit@0.4.0)

       ├── mime-types@2.1.14 (mime-db@1.26.0)

       ├── tough-cookie@2.3.2 (punycode@1.4.1)

       ├── har-validator@2.0.6 (pinkie-promise@2.0.1, commander@2.9.0, chalk@1.1.3, is-my-json-valid@2.15.0)

       ├── hawk@3.1.3 (cryptiles@2.0.5, sntp@1.0.9, boom@2.10.1, hoek@2.16.3)

       └── http-signature@1.1.1 (assert-plus@0.2.0, jsprim@1.3.1, sshpk@1.10.2)



       multer@0.1.6 node_modules/multer

       ├── qs@1.2.2

       ├── mkdirp@0.3.5

       └── busboy@0.2.14 (readable-stream@1.1.14, dicer@0.2.5)



       connect-busboy@0.0.2 node_modules/connect-busboy

       └── busboy@0.2.14 (readable-stream@1.1.14, dicer@0.2.5)



       nodemon@1.11.0 node_modules/nodemon

       ├── ignore-by-default@1.0.1

       ├── undefsafe@0.0.3

       ├── es6-promise@3.3.1

       ├── minimatch@3.0.3 (brace-expansion@1.1.6)

       ├── touch@1.0.0 (nopt@1.0.10)

       ├── lodash.defaults@3.1.2 (lodash.restparam@3.6.1, lodash.assign@3.2.0)

       ├── ps-tree@1.1.0 (event-stream@3.3.4)

       ├── update-notifier@0.5.0 (is-npm@1.0.0, semver-diff@2.1.0, string-length@1.0.1, chalk@1.1.3, repeating@1.1.3, configstore@1.4.0, latest-version@1.0.1)

       └── chokidar@1.6.1 (inherits@2.0.3, path-is-absolute@1.0.1, async-each@1.0.1, glob-parent@2.0.0, is-binary-path@1.0.1, is-glob@2.0.1, readdirp@2.1.0, anymatch@1.3.0)



       jade@1.11.0 node_modules/jade

       ├── character-parser@1.2.1

       ├── void-elements@2.0.1

       ├── commander@2.6.0

       ├── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)

       ├── jstransformer@0.0.2 (is-promise@2.1.0, promise@6.1.0)

       ├── constantinople@3.0.2 (acorn@2.7.0)

       ├── with@4.0.3 (acorn-globals@1.0.9, acorn@1.2.2)

       ├── clean-css@3.4.24 (commander@2.8.1, source-map@0.4.4)

       ├── transformers@2.1.0 (promise@2.0.0, css@1.0.8, uglify-js@2.2.5)

       └── uglify-js@2.7.5 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, async@0.2.10, yargs@3.10.0, source-map@0.5.6)



       moment@2.17.1 node_modules/moment



       execsql@0.0.3 node_modules/execsql

       ├── underscore@1.5.2

       ├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)

       └── mysql@2.0.0-rc2 (require-all@0.0.3, bignumber.js@1.0.1)



       node-hl7@0.1.3 node_modules/node-hl7

       ├── xmlbuilder@0.4.3

       ├── chai@1.4.2

       ├── xml2js@0.2.8 (sax@0.5.8)

       └── socket.io@0.9.17 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.16)

-----> Caching build

       Clearing previous node cache

       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):

       - node_modules

       - bower_components (nothing to cache)

-----> Build succeeded!

       ├── body-parser@1.16.0

       ├── connect-busboy@0.0.2

       ├── cookie-parser@1.3.5

       ├── debug@2.2.0

       ├── execsql@0.0.3

       ├── express@4.12.4

       ├── gm@1.23.0

       ├── jade@1.11.0

       ├── jsonfile@2.4.0

       ├── module@0.0.1

       ├── moment@2.17.1

       ├── morgan@1.5.3

       ├── multer@0.1.6

       ├── node-hl7@0.1.3

       ├── node-mv@0.1.3

       ├── nodemon@1.11.0

       ├── periodic-task@0.1.2

       ├── request@2.79.0

       ├── serve-favicon@2.2.1

       └── string@3.3.3



-----> Discovering process types

       Procfile declares types -> web


-----> Compressing...

       Done: 20.2M

-----> Launching...

       Released v3

       https://warm-coast-28316.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Answer (score 1):

Your log contents only show your most recent deploy of your application to Heroku. You need to retrieve the later log messages to see what happened.

I know this because every single Heroku web request generates a log entry, and your logs show none.

What you can do is this:

- Visit your Heroku app. Get the error.
- Run the `heroku logs` command to view the most recently logs (and errors).

If you want to keep your logs running while you are testing your app so you don't have to constantly repeat the `heroku logs` command, you can say:

```
$ heroku logs --tail
```

This will open a 'stream' of logs that you can continue viewing in real-time.